# Высота блока в зависимости от высоты другого блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть 3 блока:

```css
.left-menu {
        background-color: #F4F4F4;
        min-height: 750px;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
}
.center-main {
        width: 705px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        min-height: 750px;
}
.right-main {
        background-color: #F4F4F4;
        min-height: 750px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 265px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu" id="gmenu"></div>
<div class="center-main" id="center"></div>
<div class="right-main"><div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы высота левого и правого блоков всегда была равна центральному блоку?

Answer (score 1):

А ведь это классический случай, когда на помощь приходят таблицы:

```css
body {
  display: table;
  min-height: 750px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.left-menu {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  width: 200px;
}
.center-main {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 705px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.right-main {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 265px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu" id="gmenu"></div>
<div class="center-main" id="center"></div>
<div class="right-main"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример c использованием `display: table`

[Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20table)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 50px;
}

.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
     background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-menu"></div>
  <div class="center-main"></div>
  <div class="right-main">Здравствуйте, суть вопроса:
есть ли инструкции по посадке уже свёрстанного сайта на хостинг?
что бы там был охват, допустим:
.htaccess
robot.txt
xmlrpc.php (сайт на wordpress)
настройка гугл аналитики или яндекс метрики
установка базовых плагинов (если есть необходимость) security например или защита от спама
и тому подобное, спасибо.</div>
</div>
```

Пример c использованием `display: flex`;

[Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;    
}

.container > div {  
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.container > div:nth-of-type(1),
.container > div:nth-of-type(3){
     width: 25%;
}
.container > div:nth-of-type(2){
     background: #999;
     width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-menu"></div>
  <div class="center-main"></div>
  <div class="right-main">Здравствуйте, суть вопроса:
есть ли инструкции по посадке уже свёрстанного сайта на хостинг?
что бы там был охват, допустим:
.htaccess
robot.txt
xmlrpc.php (сайт на wordpress)
настройка гугл аналитики или яндекс метрики
установка базовых плагинов (если есть необходимость) security например или защита от спама
и тому подобное, спасибо.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов реализации на css, применить absolute для боковых колонок.
*В примере другие ширины колонок для наглядности.*

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: .5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #777;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 820px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.center {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: justify;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  width: 7rem;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  width: 10rem;
}


.wrap_center {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10rem 0 7rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap wrap_center">
  
  <div class="left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, ab.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="center">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non reprehenderit quis numquam sit nobis quisquam voluptatum placeat explicabo ab deleniti, dolores cupiditate, ea voluptatibus magnam sunt incidunt praesentium? Maxime laborum minima voluptatum iusto, ex similique reprehenderit illo natus eos ipsa tenetur qui dolores veritatis quod praesentium aliquid architecto corporis iste molestiae temporibus necessitatibus eaque fuga excepturi provident? Dolorem provident architecto labore, doloribus in iste ab, rerum facere, amet incidunt sunt tempore inventore perferendis unde excepturi non. Aspernatur facilis, nemo, quia id ea similique placeat! Neque ipsam porro, ratione cumque! Suscipit doloremque magni cupiditate voluptas odio, optio architecto dolores necessitatibus modi.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta a eum assumenda, velit sunt quasi totam officia quas officiis aliquid.</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia expedita ipsa molestiae ad vel inventore sequi, praesentium est libero labore explicabo corporis ducimus tenetur fugiat delectus iusto alias, consequatur laudantium, vitae error voluptatem. Temporibus maxime ratione optio quibusdam eos, voluptatem quaerat. Error vero eius sit, dolores animi facilis laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Еще один вариант с помощью **flex** для обертки блоков.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: stretch;
align-content: stretch;
```

*В примере другие ширины колонок для наглядности.*

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: .5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #777;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 820px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}

.center {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 20rem;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, ab.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non reprehenderit quis numquam sit nobis quisquam voluptatum placeat explicabo ab deleniti, dolores cupiditate, ea voluptatibus magnam sunt incidunt praesentium? Maxime laborum minima voluptatum iusto, ex similique reprehenderit illo natus eos ipsa tenetur qui dolores veritatis quod praesentium aliquid architecto corporis iste molestiae temporibus necessitatibus eaque fuga excepturi provident? Dolorem provident architecto labore, doloribus in iste ab, rerum facere, amet incidunt sunt tempore inventore perferendis unde excepturi non. Aspernatur facilis, nemo, quia id ea similique placeat! Neque ipsam porro, ratione cumque! Suscipit doloremque magni cupiditate voluptas odio, optio architecto dolores necessitatibus modi.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta a eum assumenda, velit sunt quasi totam officia quas officiis aliquid.</p>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

...