# Высота div'а в зависимости от контента

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Как сделать, чтобы div был по высоте контента? Float не используется. `.main` находится посреди страницы (`margin: auto`).

```css
#main {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content1">Текст1</div>
  <div id="content2">Текст2</div>
  <div id="content3">Текст3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А сейчас разве не так?

Comment: Четыре ответа от телепатов, хех)

Comment: @andreymal, они попрыгали с бубном и им ответ Великий Программист ответ подсказал :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Высота блока в зависимости от высоты другого блока](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561393/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: `display: inline-table; height: auto;`

Comment: мое решение на js [сыль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865320/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-2560%D1%80%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)
думаю подойдет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `display: table;` без указания высоты:

```css
#main{
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100px;
 display: table;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="main">
        <div id="content1">Текст1</div>
        <div id="content2">Текст2</div>
        <div id="content3">Текст3</div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: А зачем `body`?

Comment: @Yuri, посмотрите в вопрос, и не задавайте глупых вопросов)

Comment: Я убрал там `body` :)

Comment: @Yuri, и все теперь должны броситься редактировать ответы?

Comment: Желательно. `body` здесь бесполезный :)

Answer (score 2):

при height: auto высота всегда рассчитывается в зависимости от контента. У div'а это свойство по умолчанию auto, т.е. вам нет необходимости что-то писать

Comment: Тогда div расползается на всю высоту страницы.

Comment: абсурд, не может такого быть. Мы с вами явно говорим не про одно и то же, переформулируйте свой вопрос

Comment: Я его дополнил еще вчера. 
p.s. Решение _L. Vadim_ работает, но, чтобы div с контентом находился по центру страницы (как в первоначальном варианте с фиксированной высотой), не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте это в главный див.

```css
#main{
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100px;
        overflow:auto;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="main">
        <div id="content1">Текст1</div>
        <div id="content2">Текст2</div>
        <div id="content3">Текст3</div>
      </div>
</body>
```

И не трогайте высоту.

> Так это работает, если ставите `bottom:0` будет расползаться до низу.

Comment: Тогда див на всю высоту страницы расползается.

Comment: можете в вопрос вставить ваш css код

Comment: Все, вставил css.

Comment: я обновил код, проверьте

Comment: Работает, но как div.main отцентрировать по высоте страницы?

Comment: @Maks_Tresh, `transform: translateY(-50%);`

Comment: @Yuri, возможно я неправильно выразился, или Вы неправильно меня поняли, но при `transform: translateY(-50%);`   div.main располагается выше центра страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Он у вас и так по контенту:

```css
#main {
  background-color: red;
}

#content1, #content2, #content3 {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #202020;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content1">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="content2">Текст 1<br>Текст 2</div>
  <div id="content3">Текст 1<br>Текст 2<br>Текст 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавил css в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Clearfix — вспомогательный класс в css, с помощью которого мы исправляем схлопывающиеся размеры контейнера у плавающих элементов.

В CSS добавляется следующее правило:

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

А затем класс `clearfix` добавляется к контейнеру, внутри которого лежат флоатные колонки.

## Без `clearfix`:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
}

.columns - container {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
}

.column {
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #3498db;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
}

.column1 {
  float: left;
}

.column2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns-container">
    <div class="column column1">
      .column1<br> Первая колонка
    </div>
    <div class="column column2">
      .column2 Вторая колонка
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## C `clearfix`:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
}

.columns - container {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
}

.column {
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #3498db;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
}

.column1 {
  float: left;
}

.column2 {
  float: right;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns-container clearfix">
    <div class="column column1">
      .column1<br> Первая колонка
    </div>
    <div class="column column2">
      .column2 Вторая колонка
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: @Yuri А в чем еще, собственно, может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну я о том, что в вопросе не сказано, что он использует float

Comment: @Yuri ну вопрос «слишком общий», чтобы дать на него однозначный ответ. Но возможно проблема в этом, не у него, так у кого-то, кто найдет этот вопрос через поиск.

Comment: К сожалению, я не использую float

Answer (score 0):

Ещё есть вариант: выравнивать по середине с помощью transform

```css
#main {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content1">Текст1</div>
  <div id="content2">Текст2</div>
  <div id="content3">Текст3</div>
</div>
```