# Авто высота, мало контента, 2560рх, белая полоса

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, opencart, height

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Суть: в контента есть только #content {min-height: 600px;}
при РМ 2560*1200рх - проблема что между футером и низом екрана образуется пустое поле, для игры в футбол!

Идея: реализовать на js, так что бы HWindow(Висота екна) - HHtml(висота Html) = 
      разница; #content + разница = збс )
И ето все дело сделать респонсив ...

Но! Столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо продумать два варианта загрузки страници: HHtml>HWindow и HHtml

Прилагаю кусок кода: упростил для наглядности

```js
function HeightContent() {
    var HWindow = $(window).height();
    var HHtml = $('html').height();
    var HDiff = HWindow - HHtml;
    var HCont = $('#content').height();
    if(HDiff>0 || HHtml>HWindow){
        var HContNew = HCont + HDiff;
        $('#content').css('height',HContNew);
        alert(1);
    }else{
        $('#content').css('height',HCont);
        alert(2);
    }
}

//$(window).on('load', HeightContent);
//$(window).on('resize',HeightContent);
$(window).on('load resize', HeightContent);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff
}

header, footer {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #80ce7d;
  height: 100px
}

#content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #dc7d6b;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header><h1>header</h1></header>
    <div id="content"> </div>
<footer><h1>footer</h1></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо [Геннадий Журов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/275019/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%96%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2), что подсказал!
Етот вопрос еще називается: "**Прижать футер к нижней части экрана**" или "**Футер и центральный блок**" и тд...

Еще раз **суть**: если высота Window > Html, например при РМ 2560*1600рх - то между футером и низом екрана образуется пустое поле.

**Сделяль**: на js, и ето все дело респонсив... Код лисапедный для наглядности.

Кому надо юзайте, если есть конструктивная критика - радо послушаю

```
function NewHContent() {
    var content = $('#content');
    content.css('height','auto');

    var HWindow = $(window).height();
    var HHtml = $('html').height();
    var HDiff = HWindow - HHtml;

    if(HDiff>0){
        var HCont = content.height();
        var HContNew = HCont + HDiff;
        content.css('height',HContNew);
    }
}

$(window).on('load resize', NewHContent);
```